# Arrays and nested Arrays in Vue.JS

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-directives

In a component I have these arrays :

```
export default {
  data() {

    return {

      userGrades: [
        [course= "Mathematics"], [grade = 18 ],
        [course= "Physics"], [grade = 15 ],
      ],


      userSubscriptions: [
        [option= "Swiming Pool"], [price = 60 ],
        [option= "Fiteness Club"], [price = 30 ],
      ],


      userContact: [(phone = "00000000"), (fax = "11111111")],



    }
```

I want to use neted v-for directives to list them.
With a single array, it's straight forward,
but when I use nested v-for, the code compiles, but nothing  is rendered

Comment: Can you add your template i.e listing code???

Comment: What are those arrays, what exactly is in there? This shouldn't compile.

Comment: It compiles, but not at all to what you expect it to; what you've defined is `{userGrades: [["Mathematics"], [18], ["Physics"], [15]], userSubscriptions: [["Swiming Pool"], [60], ["Fiteness Club"], [30]], userContact: ["00000000", "11111111"]} `, because all of those `foo = bar` chunks just end up returning `bar`.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the arrays you should declare.

```
userGrades: [
{
    course: 'Mathematics',
    grade: 18
},
{
    course: 'Physics',
    grade: 15
}],
userSubscriptions: [
{
    option: "Swiming Pool",
    price: 60
},
{
    option: "Fiteness Club",
    price: 30
}],
userContact: [
{
    phone: "00000000"
},
{
    fax: "11111111"
}]
```

You can iterate through them as =>

```
<div v-for="item in userGrades">
{{item.course}}=>{{item.grade}}
</div>
```

Same for all other array objects.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript does not have the idea of nested associative arrays. You must use object notation:

```
userGrades: [
  {
      course: 'Mathematics',
      grade: 18
  }
]
```